# Edit data with a dynamic show/hide form with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm new in jQuery and I learn fast but really I need help.

I have a page containing data like this example :

The page have a dive called **"content"** (id)

This div contains 2 sub divs : one for data and one for form called respectively **div-data** and **div-form**.

[image]

Initially, "div-data" is shown and the other is hidden.

When I click edit  "div-data" disappear and "div-form" appear with a filled form of data.

I made data validation and all it's fine, the edited data is updated on DB, so I must hide "div-form" 
and show "div-form", but the problem, the data in "div-data" is not updated.

How can I do to update that div???

I'm in the last step :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the have the values in a separate element whose content you can replace.

Then you can fill those elements from the ajax success function:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#div-data').find('.firstname').text(data.firstname).end()
        .find('.lastname').text(data.lastname).end()
        .find('.work').text(data.work);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's truth ! Because you update the data in **#div-form / input** rather than **#div-data** , after you hiding **#div-form** and showing **#div-data**, you would see the **old** data stored in **#div-data**.

There are too many solutions, so I pick up a simple one for you (pseudo code without testing) :

Add some common classes to both places.

```
var $div_data_cache = $('#div-data');

$('#div-form input').each(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('className');

    $div_data_cache.find(className).html( $(this).val() )            
});
```

in this way, after pressing "ok", this script will help you synchronize data between each other.

Notes: If you dont care too much about cross browser problems , you can use the new attribute introduced in HTML5 called **contenteditable**

Now , you can set this attr for all sub-divs in **#div-data**, and set some events to trigger validations / db operations after finishing editing !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you rather switch the disabled option on your form input fields? This way, you only need one div in your DOM and you don't have to care about DOM manipulation.

This is what I'm talking about:

Let's say your EDIT button's id is 'form-edit':

```
$('#form-edit').click(function(){
    $('#div-form').find('input ').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('disabled')) $this.removeAttr('disabled');
                else $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp